# Serial Port data

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, usb, pyserial

I am attempting to read the data from an Absolute Encoder with a USB interface using pyserial on the Raspberry. The datasheet for the encoder is below. The USB interface data is on page 22-23

https://www.rls.si/eng/fileuploader/download/download/?d=0&file=custom%2Fupload%2FData-sheet-AksIM-offaxis-rotary-absolute-encoder.pdf

I have successfully connected to the Encoder and I am able to send commands using

```
port = serial.Serial("/dev/serial/by-id/usb-RLS_Merilna_tehnkis_AksIM_encoder_3454353-if00")

port.write(b"x")
```

where x is any of the available Commands listed for the USB interface.

For example `port.write(b"1")` is meant to initiate a single position request. I am able to print the output from encoder with

```
x = port.read()

print(x)
```

The problem is converting the output into actual positiong data. `port.write(b"1")` outputs the following data:

```
b'\xea\xd0\x05\x00\x00\x00\xef'
```

I know that the first and last bytes are just the header and footer. Bytes 5 and 6 are the encoder status. Bytes 2-4 is the actual position data. The customer support has informed me that I need to take bytes 2 to 4, shift them into a 32 bit unsigned integer (into lower 3 bytes), convert to a floating point number, divide by 0xFF FF FF, multiply by 360. Result are degrees.

I'm not exactly sure how to do this. Can someone please let me know the python prgramming/functions I need to write in order to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Integer is: 3 bytes binary absolute position, big-endian, left aligned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use builtin `from_bytes()` method:

```
x = b'\xea\xd0\x05\x00\x00\x00\xef'

number = 360 * float(
    int.from_bytes(x[1:4], 'big')  # get integer from bytes
) / 0xffffff

print(number)
```

will print:

```
292.5274832563092
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to implement this but occasionally I am getting byte values that look like `b '@'` or `b 'z'`. How do I convert these characters into the right values?

Comment: @GeraldParker I do not understand you. Where do you get b'@' and b'z'?

Comment: for example when I send the the encoder is in certain position I may get      b '\xea'

b '\x9e'

b '\xe9'

`b '@'`

b '\x00'

b '\x00'

b '\xef'   I am still able to convert the number into position data using the formula you provided even with the `b'@'`. I assume this is still a byte value. I guess my question is why is it sometimes providing these characters instead of a hex number?

Comment: sorry the comment above was suppose to say  "when I send a command to the encoder for position data*"

Comment: What you are seeing is just an artifact of python trying to print something readable. The underlying data is still the same and since you report that the conversion works ok, you can ignore this: eg `print(b'\x40') -> b'@'` the data is still hex 0x40, but the ascii is '@'

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to extract the bytes and shift them into an integer and scale as a float:

```
x = b'\xea\xd0\x05\x00\x00\x00\xef'

print(x)

int_value = 0   # initialise shift register
for index in range(1,4):
    int_value *= 256          # shift up by 8 bits
    int_value += x[index]     # or in the next byte
print(int_value)

# scale the integer against the max value
float_value = 360 * float(int_value) / 0xffffff
print(float_value)
```

Output:

```
b'\xea\xd0\x05\x00\x00\x00\xef'
13632768
292.5274832563092
```